# Need Facebook page open in ios app not in safari

Tags: ios, facebook

Here is my code:

```
NSURL *fanPageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/210227459693"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: fanPageURL];
```

I want this URL to open in my iOS app in any UIview controller, but it opens in Safari. How can I achieve this?

Comment: as your url suggest, it will open facebook application in browser., to open facebook page your need to change your URL

Comment: hello @humza do you want to open your profile page in your viewController?

Answer (score 1):

Create one UIWebView in you UIViewController and load `NSURL *fanPageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/210227459693"];` in your UIWebView. and you can use `UIWebView` Delegate method to handel more functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fanPageURL]];
```

Here webView is your Webview name which you used in your project.